# does j2me support cloud integration

Tags: java, java-me

A client of mine needs an app that can run on nokia j2me,symbian,s40,s60 and android.

Now,my question is this.Is it possible to connect a j2me app to a web server to exchange data with the app,more like a json data exchange from a php server

And by the way,what is the learning for j2me for someone who doesn't know java because I only have 3 weeks to develop this and I don't know java for now

I really wish to know about the learnibg curve. anybody?

And if you will like to know,it's a question and answer game with the questions database been generated from cloud based web server

Comment: yes it can send and receive data to/from server. [Google](http://www.google.com) is your friend to learn anything.

Answer (score 2):

I began learning J2ME back in 2006, and had a little Java experience.
It took me 3 years before I felt I had a good grip on J2ME, because of all the fragmentation and device bugs there also is. But to be fair, it was only a sparetime project, so I didn't have a whole lot of time for it. But 3 weeks for learning is way too little.

When I looked into Android I found it more difficult to learn than J2ME. I personally think there are many weird design decisions in Android that doesn't make any sense. I prefer J2ME.

But Android devices runs J2ME MIDlets just fine, when you install phoneME.
http://davy.preuveneers.be/phoneme/
The latest version even offers shortcut creations so you can start your MIDlet from your Android desktop.

As Randyka says, there are no problems creating an HTTP connection with J2ME. But it doesn't come with a JSON parser, so you'll either have to find a 3rd party API for that, or else create your own protocol.